# Message Computer Over IP/Port

Tags: powershell, vbscript, sms-gateway

I'm having some trouble with this, and have a hard time explaining the problem in words, but I will do the best I can.

I would like to send a simple message to a computer from a different computer. Nothing fancy. I have done some research, and a lot of sources say to create a script that accesses the built-in MSG.EXE function in Windows (I am currently on Windows 10) however, this only seems to work on machines connected to LAN.

From what I have gathered, I would need to create a website that handles the requests: get message from Computer A and send it to Computer B. Could I do this (In Powershell or VBS) without having to make a site specifically for it?

**What I want:**
I want Computer A to send a plain-text message to Computer B. Preferably, when the message is successfully sent a message box will appear that says "From: (whomever) and the message. Using MSG.EXE did what I wanted it to do, however it only worked with LAN-connected devices. Could I make this work with static IP? If so, how?

**Additional Information:**

The two computers are not on a LAN, but are connected to the Internet.

Computer A (the sender) and Computer B (the receiver) each have a static IP address, however that can obviously change.

Ports are available in each computer.

I have a Raspberry Pi that could act as a server "middle man" should that be required.

To be very clear: There are a lot of posts that talk about sending messages over LAN. I am NOT trying to send a message over LAN. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need a server of some cert (either a VPN or a messaging server)

Comment: Essentially, I could set up the RPi to be the server? If it's possible I'll trudge through the internet to find out how (although some pointers would be excruciatingly helpful)

Comment: Just use Socket.io; it lets you easily do this kind of push notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're being quite vague in why you want it and what you want it to do; the main problem is that home internet connections are built for things to connect out, and nothing to connect in.

Fixes:

- [Port forwarding](http://portforward.com/) where you say "incoming connections go to this or that computer.
- Building a service where both sides "connect out", i.e. you have a website hosted somewhere out on the internet. One computer connects out to send the message, the other connects out to check for messages.

Outside that, the next problem is knowing where on the internet to connect to.

Fixes:

- Hard code the end points. Static IPs are good for this because [the definition of a static IP](https://support.google.com/fiber/answer/3547208?hl=en) is that it's an address which doesn't change. Mysteriously, you have static IPs which can change and you consider that 'obvious'. (??)
- DNS where you register a domain, and the computers look at a domain name for where to connect. You update DNS with the current IP.
- DNS where you use [a free DNS service on someone else's name](http://lifehacker.com/the-best-free-alternatives-to-dyndns-1561556205) and your service listener updates that as its IP changes.

And after that, most people's computers/laptops/phones are switched off or in low power sleep mode most of the time, and their internet connections are comparatively unreliable, so any random message probably won't be answered.

Fixes:

- Use a serious website service
- Run an always-on computer to be that service
- Deal with it being offline and messages being flakey
- Use a store-and-forward system like email, which queues and retries, like e-mail and instant messengers do

> get message from Computer A and send it to Computer B. Could I do this (In Powershell or VBS) without having to make a site specifically for it?

Yes. Quick answer: pick a port, configure site B's modem/router to forward the port to computer B. Open the port on computer B's firewall. Write [some kind of TCP socket listener](http://poshcode.org/4601) on Computer B, and the sender on Computer A, connecting to the public IP address of site B.

Long answer: then enjoy writing your own messaging protocol, error handling, message authentication, etc.

Alternative: do the same but going to your rPi. Have it listening. Not in powershell (sadly) or vbscript (luckily), and have it serve the messages up by HTTP/JSON, both computers invoke-webrequest or invoke-restmethod and post/get them with regular polling.

Comment: Thank you for the informative reply! After doing some more research, I indeed was being lazy and trying to find a quick fix to a complicated problem. I have decided on creating a website or app that runs through a server (whether that be a computer, RPi, etc) to handle it.